# Kibana dashboard to show average time difference

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I want to create a visualization in Kibana which shows the average response time.

I have these 2 time stamp fields :
state_time
end_time

I am calculating the average response time as:
**avg response time = avg (start time - end time).**

Can i achieve tis using some formula in Kibana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [runtime field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime-mapping-fields.html) can help you to achieve this.

```
PUT test_kibana_time_diff/_doc/1
{
  "end_time": "2023-06-06T16:21:15.000Z",
  "start_time": "2023-06-06T15:21:15.000Z"
}
```

---

```
PUT test_kibana_time_diff/_mapping
{
  "runtime": {
    "time_diff_minutes": {
      "type": "long",
      "script": {
        "source": "emit((doc['end_time'].value.millis - doc['start_time'].value.millis) / (1000 * 60))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks . This solution should work but unfortunately i do not have access to introduce a runtime field.  can it be performed via scripted field ?

Comment: Yes, the same script will also work with scripted fields.

Comment: Hi , thanks it worked ..But is there a way to get the difference in case the 2 fields are part of different log line . for e.g one logline contains only start_time and another log line contains only end_time .

Comment: Happy to hear it worked. You can use transform if the start_time and end_time fields are in separate documents and if the documents has some correlation id.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-overview.html